# Child Record delete invoking Parent trigger

Tags: trigger, master-detail

I have written a trigger on Parent__c Object (after insert,after update-This trigger creates a child__c record depending on few conditions). But when i am deleting child__c record, it invokes this parent object trigger and recreates a child record.
FYI-There is no trigger on Child__c which may cause the Parent__c trigger to fire.Parent__c - child__c relation is Master-Detail.
Please help me.is it a standard behaviour or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have roll-up summary fields in you parent object? If so, deleting the child object may change the roll-up summary field value, and thus fire the trigger on update for the parent.